# Multiple upload in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Hi I'm a beginner in CakePHP 3.0 my I have a problem, it won't save in database.

Controller:

```
public function add() {
    $myTable = TableRegistry::get('Files');
        $data = $this->request->getData();
        $file = $myTable->newEntities($data);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        foreach ($file as $key => $val) {
            $val['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $val['filename'] = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
            $val['file_location'] = '../uploads/files/';
            $val['file_type'] = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
            $val['file_size'] = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
            $val['file_status'] = 'Active';
            $val['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $val['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            if($myTable->save($val)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('File has been uploaded and inserted successfully.'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('File not upload!'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can someone help me to fixed my problem, I followed the docs in CakePHP but it seems not working.

Views:

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['type' => 'file', 'url' => ['controller' => 'Files', 'action' => 'add']]) ?>
echo $this->Form->input('photo[]', ['type' => 'file','multiple' => 'true','label' => 'Upload Multiple Photos']);
```

This is my database structure:

```
  CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_location` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_size` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function add() {
    $myTable = TableRegistry::get('Files');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        foreach ($_FILES['photo'] as $key => $file) {
            $val['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $val['filename'] = $file['name'];
            $val['file_location'] = '../uploads/files/';
            $val['file_type'] = $file['type'];
            $val['file_size'] = $file['size'];
            $val['file_status'] = 'Active';
            $val['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $val['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


            $val = $myTable->newEntity($val);
            //Make some count here to trace the no of files uploaded and take this if else out of this foreach, otherwise it will display many flash message. 
            if($myTable->save($val)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('File has been uploaded and inserted successfully.'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('File not upload!'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post that pr($_FILES);die; prints.

Comment: i change my code i use for loop but saving not work. then my saving function is this
$table = TableRegistry::get('Files');
$entities = $table->newEntities($file);
$table->saveMany($entities); but it doesnt work